# VSCode CSS Hovers in WebStorm

Tags: css, sass, webstorm

How do I get Visual Studio Code [hovers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_hovers) in WebStorm?

In VSCode, when you write some CSS/SCSS you can get a hover that would show "an HTML snippet that is matched by the CSS rule". I find this extremely useful.

Is there such a feature in WebStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature, please vote for [WEB-35464](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35464) to be notified on any progress with this request